# Is it safe to use Yii2's Yii::$app->params function to pass a lot of parameters dynamically? Or is there another way?

Tags: php, yii2

I have to pass a variable to a layout in Yii2. Since the layouts aren't rendered in the controllers, I can't pass the variables using the usual method:

```
$this->render(['index', 'id' => $id]);
```

Now I have searched the internet for passing a variable from a controller to a layout, most answers I have seen are storing the variables in the params function of Yii2.

Is this safe? I have to pass a lot of variables, and each of them dynamically using a tickbox. Is there another way?

Comment: Show your code. It is safe to use params ,but you can use variable in layout which comes from controller.

Comment: Already got it man, I made a work around, I rendered the layout inside the view file then passed the parameter, removed the classes of divisions and such.

Answer (score 0):

maybe using blocks:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-views.html

```
<?php $this->beginBlock('block1'); ?>

...content of block1...

<?php $this->endBlock(); ?>

...

<?php $this->beginBlock('block3'); ?>

...content of block3...

<?php $this->endBlock(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this one!